# Changing window selection size of wxChoice

Tags: python, wxpython

I am working on a python application with large fonts, and I'm using wxPython 2.8.12.  This results in very large selection windows for wx.Choice controls when there are more than 30 items.  I would like to subclass Choice to be able to set at the number of items to display before adding the scroll.  This is a hard-coded value in choice.cpp in the method DoSetSize line 570:

```
size_t nItems = GetCount();
if (!HasFlag(wxCB_SIMPLE))
{
    if ( !nItems )
        nItems = 9;
    else if ( nItems > 30 )
        nItems = 30;
}
```

Is there a way for me to override this somehow?  I've tried overriding the DoGetSize method in my subclass, that didn't work at all.  Is this impossible because it's implemented in the c++ source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://wiki.wxpython.org/OverridingMethods

Although things have changed somewhat in the new wxPython Phoenix, and `DoSetSize` is now overridable there, it probably wouldn't be any help to you in this case because most of the rest of the code in the C++ implementation of `wxChoice::DoSetSize` is using or setting things that are not in the public API and are unavailable from Python.